# FreeRtos how to store function address while context switching

Tags: freertos, stm32f4

I using freertos on my project. My code is stuck in hardfault handler, I want know last executed function address or last executed line address for debugging.How to debug code when PC is pointing Hardfault handler.

Answer (score 1):

That information is 100% dependent on which microcontroller you are using, and also which tool chain you are using as some IDEs will do this for you.  You failed to provide either piece of information, so are asking people to guess on your behalf.  A good question is one that cannot only possibly be answered by another question.

I am going to guess you are using a Cortex-M microcontroller, in which case information on debugging a hard fault can be found on lots of links found by Google, including the following: http://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html

Comment: I am using IAR IDE and STM32f412rgy microcontroller, hardware file generated by stmcuemx software. I have gone through that link but it is useful when you are code is not stuck in event handler. My code is got stucked after 3 days in Hardfault_handler.